# configuring maven plugin with a custom packaging

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have written a custom maven plugin which works in package phase of maven's default life cycle. In addition I have added a custom packaging type to it. In order to support the custom packaging type I have introduced components.xml so it will override the default maven life cycle. In the component/configuration/lifecycles/lifecycle/phases/package section of component.xml I have added my plugin to execute in package phase.

When I use my plugin I pass the configuration to the plugin through the pom.xml as follows;

```
<build>
   ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>sampleArtifact</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            ...
             <executions>
                 <executions>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goal>generate</generate>
                    <configuration>
                    //Configuration goes here.
                    </configuration>
                 </executions>
             </executions>
             ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

Problem:
the configuration I passed into mojo as above is not getting set in the mojo. However, if I set the plugin configuration in one level below the  tag(where the executions tag present), then it works. Since this plugin works in package phase I need the plugin configuration passed in through as above. Without custom packaging, the above configuration works well. Any thoughts on what I miss here?

Comment: First why have you written an plugin for what purpose? And how did you called it?

Comment: A1. I need to package some files in a particular format. Thus I written a plugin. A2. How I called is mentioned above in my original question.